# Reflector in Conway's Game of Life on Triangular Tessellations

Tags: cellular-automata

Back in 1994, Carter Bays reports in ["Cellular Automata in the Triangular Tessellation"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b4f/fa2475e323b51ecdf6039aa71dcb616b3779.pdf) that there are at least 6 Games of Life (GoL) living on triangular tessellations. A GoL has at least one glider (translating oscillator) and doesn't grow unbounded. I wonder, whether any of the mentioned GoLs has a [reflector](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Reflector), by which I mean a configuration that changes the angle of the gliders propagation (by 120°, I assume...)

$\hskip1.9in$[image]

Comment: Not sure how many existing GoL search or simulation tools support this lattice, but I suspect there are some. At least [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/) can apparently [emulate such rules via a helper script](https://github.com/GollyGang/ruletablerepository/wiki/RoadMap), basically mapping them into 4-state CA on a square lattice, with each cell encoding the state of two adjacent triangles. Maybe not the most user-friendly method, but at least it means that any search script that uses Golly as its simulation engine (and can be made to work with the encoding) could in principle be adapted.